# My app crashes on Startup(java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider)

Tags: android, crash, android-multidex

My Application was running fine from last week but today it has been crashed on startup with the same code.
I was not changed code from last week.
I do not know why this happen.
Please Help me soon.

**LogCat Error**

```
06-11 00:53:19.400 9515-9515/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.jaffteach.medicare, PID: 9515
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jaffteach.medicare-yxLqDL7JptwmV2rJYJClrA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Gradle: app**

My gradle is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jaffteach.medicare"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
                }
            }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please Tell me the best solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally**
I searched a lot and now the solution that is worked for me is

> just disable Instant Run

***For Disable Instant Run***

Simple go to

> 1. Settings
> 2. Build, Execution, Deployment
> 3. Instant Run
> 4. and Unchecked Enable Instant Run